# picking up a path in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, path

I need some help with my js file.  I an using a bit of javascript to show some xml on a page and I need to reference the right xml file according to the page that it is on.  e.g.

```
<script>
xml=loadXMLDoc("product.xml");
</script>
```

I have the all the xml files named as different products and have printed out the reference to the xml on the page that it should be on

```
<div id="product">/xmlfolder/item001.xml</div>
```

What I need to do is somehow reference the path on the page to the javascript.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
xml=loadXMLDoc(document.getElementById('prodct').innerHTML);
```